# How to do laravel eloquent table with joins, orwhere and pagination correctly?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

This is my original code where i display all data for team users.

```
 $data = Teamuser::join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'team_user.team_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'team_user.user_id')
            ->get(['users.name as username','teams.name','users.email','team_user.role','team_user.id','team_user.user_id','team_user.team_id']);
```

However, since im developing a search function for the table. I try adding orwhere to the function.

```
$data = Teamuser::join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'team_user.team_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'team_user.user_id')
            ->get(['users.name as username','teams.name','users.email','team_user.role','team_user.id','team_user.user_id','team_user.team_id'])
            ->where('users.name', 'like', '%'.$request->search2.'%')
            ->orWhere('teams.name', 'like', '%'.$request->search2.'%')
            ->orWhere('team_user.role', 'like', '%'.$request->search2.'%')
            ->orWhere('users.email', 'like', '%'.$request->search2.'%')->paginate(5);
```

But the search function doesnt work, how do i format the syntax in a correct way?

Comment: Have you ran the query generated from Eloquent directly into SQL editor?

Comment: I would use `with()`instead of join and set the relation in your model. Then search the documentation on `orWhereHas()``

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? He returned an exception?

Comment: Do you have relationships between Team and User? How are your model relationships structured? Are you trying to get mainly users or teams?

Comment: It returns this error after use tosql() ```local.ERROR: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orWhere does not exist. {"userId":4,"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::orWhere does not exist. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Eurotracks\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Macroable\\Traits\\Macroable.php:113)
[stacktrace]```. Im sure this is just a format error because i tried using a table without joins and it works immediately

Comment: Read my answer, i think the problem is the bad usage of `get([])` instead of `select([])`

Comment: That error is because you are using`get()` before `orWhere()` clausules. Once you do `get()`, the response is converted to a collection and `orWhere()` doesn't exist on collections.
In order to do `orWehere()` in your query, you need to move `get()` to the bottom line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you are using `get()` correctly, but i purpose you an alternative syntax

```
$data = Teamuser::select(['users.name as username','teams.name','users.email','team_user.role','team_user.id','team_user.user_id','team_user.team_id'])
            ->join('teams', 'teams.id', '=', 'team_user.team_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'team_user.user_id')
            ->where('users.name', 'like', '%'.$request->search2.'%')
            ->orWhere('teams.name', 'like', '%'.$request->search2.'%')
            ->orWhere('team_user.role', 'like', '%'.$request->search2.'%')
            ->orWhere('users.email', 'like', '%'.$request->search2.'%')
            ->paginate(5);
```

Check if your join is correct, maybe you could use `leftJoin()` instead of `join()`

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm, turns out I only need to get rid of get() or move it to the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TeamUserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $teamUsers = Teamuser::query()
        ->with('team', 'user')
        ->search(request('search2'))
        ->paginate(5);
...

    // App/Models/TeamUser

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function scopeSearch($query, string $terms = null)
    {
        collect(explode(' ', $terms))->filter()->each(function ($term) use ($query) {
                $term = '%'.$term.'%';
                $query->where(function ($query) use ($term) {
                    $query->where('role', 'like', $term)
                        ->orWhereHas('team', function ($query) use ($term) {
                            $query->where('name', 'like', $term);
                        })
                        ->orWhereHas('user', function ($query) use ($term) {
                            $query->where('name', 'like', $term)
                                  ->where('email', 'like', $term);
                        });
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: explain your answer, don't just add code

Comment: No offence; used question code; everything is self explanatory.